# Should I define a separate partition to share files with Windows?

Tags: partition, windows, dual-boot

Windows10 / Linux Mint dual boot.

Usually, when I needed to exchange files between the two OSs, I'd boot Linux (since it sees Windows partitions out of the box), then mount the Windows partition, then copy / move / create / delete files on both partitions as I needed.

Now however I have one specific file which I'd pretty much like to be available two both OSs all the time.

I can now:

1. Create a separate NTFS partition for this purpose, configure both OSs to automout it;
2. Configure Linux to automout the Windows partition.

My intuition tells me that experienced power users would likely recommend the first option; is this true?

And if it is true, then why? What are the benefits of the first approach over the second one?

As of now I can only see one drawback: I am hereby setting the shared storage to a fixed size.

Comment: The first. You don't have to deal with all the files in the windows partition, which ca also be risky if you delete accidentally some files; and you can have troubles mounting the windows partition if windows didn't have a clean shutdown.

Comment: Yes, definitely #1. There's a small chance of file corruption if writing to the Windows system partition from outside. Always better to 1. Disable Fast Startup in Windows and 2. Use a data partition for shared files.